# Simple optimization

Tags: calculus

On my test I was suppose to minimize the amount of material used to make a box. H = height and S = side length.

The volume is 8000 units squared

$s^2 * h = 8000$ = $h=8000/s^2$

$area = 4sh + s^2$ the same as $ 4s(8000/s^2) +s^2 = area$

$ 4s(8000/s^2) +s^2= 0$
$ 4s(8000/s^2) = -s^2$
$ 32000 = -s^3$

Now I am stuck and not sure how to factor this any further. What went wrong? Obviously the box can not be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let’s clean up some minor errors. First, the volume is $8000$ units *cubed*; if it were squared, it would be an area. Next, it’s incorrect to write $$s^2h=8000=h=8000/s^2\;:$$ you don’t really mean that $h=8000$. Your second $=$ doesn’t mean *equals*; it means something like *implies*. You should write $$s^2h=8000,\text{ so }h=\frac{8000}{s^2}$$ or something of the sort.

Now let’s get to the meat of it. I’ll use $A$ for the surface area of the box, which I assume is a square box with no top. If so, you’re quite right: $A=4sh+s^2$, and when you combine this with the volume requirement, you get $$A=4s\left(\frac{8000}{s^2}\right)+s^2\;,$$ which you could simplify to $$A=\frac{32000}s+s^2\;.$$

Now why did you set this equal to $0$? That would make the area $0$, which is plainly impossible.

You want to *minimize* $A$: to find the values of $s$ and $h$ that make $A$ as small as possible. Since you already know how to get $h$ from $s$, you really just have to find the value of $s$ that minimizes $A$. That’s a basic calculus problem: find the minimum of the function $$A(s)=\frac{32000}s+s^2\;.$$ To do that you first find the derivative $A'(s)$, then set *that* equal to $0$ to find critical points, and proceed from there. I’ll let you take a crack at that on your own before I go any further.